# sed + how to replace numbers with parenthesis with sed/awk/other

Tags: bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, sed, awk, perl

we want to relapse the `[1023,1024,1022]` as described in the following file , with `[1022]`

```
more file.exm

{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":0,"replicas":[1023,1024,1022]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":1,"replicas":[1024,1022,1023]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":2,"replicas":[1022,1023,1024]},
```

expected output

```
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":0,"replicas":[1022]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":1,"replicas":[1022]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":2,"replicas":[1022]},
```

we try

```
 sed -i s'/[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]/[1022]/g'  file.exm
```

but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{4\},[0-9]\{4\},[0-9]\{4\}/1022/'
```

where

- `\{4\}` is for exactly 4 occurences.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is not correct, because you expect each time to have only 1 digit per number. Instead, try this:

```
sed -i s'/[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+/1022/g'  file.exm
```

If the `+` does not work with your version of `sed`, replace it with a `*`:

```
sed -i s'/[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*/1022/g'  file.exm
```

If you want to test your regular expressions, I suggest you to use one of the online sites like https://regex101.com/

Comment: This will add extra square brackets.

Comment: True, I copy-pasted too quickly. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `awk` solution:

```
$ awk  -F':' '{ print $1":"$2":"$3":[1022]}," }' file.exm
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":0,"replicas":[1022]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":1,"replicas":[1022]},
{"topic":"nj_hgf_dfgef","partition":2,"replicas":[1022]},
$
```